# unable to convert the sweave file into a pdf document using rstudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, sweave

I am trying to convert a tex document to pdf by running:

this is the file:

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

<<LBY, echo=FALSE>>=
library(zoo)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(xtable)
library(forecast)
library(data.table)
library(xtable)
library(RODBC)
library(chron)
library(xts)
library(grid)
library(ggthemes)


@


\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\title{Servera Lite Implementation \\ Pre/Post Resource And Transaction Analysis}
\author{Capacity Planning Engineers}
\maketitle
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{Servera LITE}
Split Login and DB write operation, reduce customer impact and increase capacity by adding 2 additional Lpars for customer login only.

This report will hightlight Resource utilization, transaction, response times during pre and post implementation of the project. For detail and more information please visit:
\url{http://cigpcapacity.jpmchase.net}
\pagebreak


\section{Servera DB}
\subsection{% CPU Utilization}


<<echo=FALSE>>=

sql<-c("SELECT T.LPAR, T.\"DATE\", T.\"usr\", T.\"sys\" , T.\"pc\" FROM db_table T WHERE T.\"LPAR\" in ('servera', 'serverb') and T.\"DATE\">SYSDATE-30")


  tryCatch({
            ch=odbcConnect("perfcap",pwd = "chase101")
            res<-sqlQuery(ch,sql)
            },error = function(e) {
            print(odbcGetErrMsg(ch))          
            })
            odbcClose(ch)

x<-res

###Servera WEEKLY CPU PROCESSING
x$Day<-weekdays(x$DATE)
x$cpu<-x$usr+x$sys
x<-x[, c("LPAR", "DATE", "cpu", "pc")]
colnames(x)<-c("server", "date", "cpu", "pc")
x$time<-format(x$date, "%H:%M:%S")
x$time<-times(x$time)
apply.periodly <- function (x, FUN, period, k=1, ...) 
        {
          if (!require("xts")) {
            stop("Need 'xts'")
          }
          ep <- endpoints(x, on=period, k=k)
          period.apply(x, ep, FUN, ...)
        }

###peak cpu for 180 minutes interval for weekly data

         mydata.xts <- xts(x$cpu, order.by = x$date)
         mydata.180M <- apply.periodly(x = mydata.xts, FUN = max, period = "minutes", k = 60)   
         new_df<-data.frame(date=index(mydata.180M), coredata(mydata.180M))
         colnames(new_df)<-c("date", "cpu")

weekly_cpu<-new_df
weekly_cpu$date<-format(round(weekly_cpu$date, units="hours"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
weekly_cpu$date<-as.POSIXct(weekly_cpu$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

weekly_cpu$time1<-format(weekly_cpu$date, "%H:%M:%S")
weekly_cpu$time1<-times(weekly_cpu$time1)
weekly_cpu<-subset(weekly_cpu, time1 > times(c("07:00:00")) & time1 < times(c("18:00:00")))
weekly_cpu<-weekly_cpu[,c(1,2)]
weekly_cpu$day<-weekdays(weekly_cpu$date)
weekly_cpu<-subset(weekly_cpu, day %in% c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"))


@
\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE, width=15, height=10>>=
        print(ggplot()+geom_point(data=subset(weekly_cpu, date< as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-09 23:59:59"))),aes(date, cpu), size=0.5, colour='blue') + 
        geom_point(data=subset(weekly_cpu, date> as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-09 23:59:59"))),aes(date, cpu), size=0.7, colour='red')+
        theme_bw()+ylim(0,100)+ylab("% CPU")+xlab("Date")+ggtitle(paste("Servera Database","\n","% CPU Utilization"))+
        geom_smooth(data=subset(weekly_cpu, date<as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-09 23:59:59"))),aes(date,cpu),method="loess", size=1.5, colour="blue", se=T)+
        geom_segment(aes(x = as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-12 12:00:00")), y = 80, xend = as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-12 12:00:00")), yend = 65), colour="red",size=1,arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")))+

annotate("text", x=as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-10 00:00:00")),y=90,label="Servera Lite went live",size=3,colour="red")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+theme_igray())


@

\end{center}




\end{document}
pdflatex test.tex
```

I received this error:

```
[2] ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ae\t1aett.fd") [3])
Runaway argument?
{\par \par \begin {center} \includegraphics {test-003} \par \end {cen\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.
<inserted text>
                \par
```

I am extremely new to latex. Any ideas what I might be doing there. I verified that all of the brackets match.

Comment: @ypnos, I just included the file.

Comment: Whats the deal with these non-latex elements in the file? This file does not work with latex.

Comment: That's not a LaTeX document yet! What Sweave does (or preferably knitr) is take what should be a `.Rnw` file and turn it into a `.tex` file, which LaTeX can then compile to a PDF. You're trying to skip the first step!

Comment: Also, I don't think you should put any code chunks, e.g., your first `LBY` chunk, in the frontmatter. Put it after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @shujaa, sorry I've asked the question wrong. I'll correct it.

Comment: @shujaa, I've made that change, I keep getting this error: [2] ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ae\t1aett.fd") [3])
Runaway argument?
{\par \par \par \begin {center} \par \includegraphics {test-003} \par \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.
<inserted text>
                \par
<*> test.tex

Comment: try commenting out `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\subsection{% CPU Utilization}`, you should save this file as `xyz.Rnw` and run `knit2pdf("xyz.Rnw")`

Comment: This well generate `xyz.log` and `xyz.tex`, you can then check for  errors if any, in the .log file

Comment: @Osssan, if I take out \subsection{% CPU Utilization}, it works. Any ideas, what might be hapening. I need to use the subsetions.

Comment: `%`, `@` etc. have special meaning in `latex`, use `\%` to generate `%` sign, check this page for more (http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols)